# Regular expression to determine each and every attribute of an anchor tag inside HTML content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I basically wanted the values of each and every attribute. The attributes may be optional and the `href` may contain HTTP or HTTPS.

A sample anchor tag inside content is:

```
 <a class=\"direct_link\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://google.com\">link text</a>
```

Sample HTML content is:

```
<p><br></p><h1>A beautiful <a class=\"f-link\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"fake.com/abc.html\">jQuery</a>; a</h1><h3 class=\"text-light\">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</h3><p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

Comment: Does the data you want to parse only include the anchor tag itself, or is it the whole HTML page? Does the anchor tag include the slashes as you've pasted them above?

Comment: @simpleigh Yes It will include the slashes and It will contain HTML content coming from a WYSWYG editor.

Comment: @Unihedron Added ruby as preferred language, I am using match/scan method

Comment: In general its not a good to parse html with regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @achingfingers Agreed But I basically wanted to update all those links with some new values, So I am going to replace old links with new ones

Comment: What matches do you want from the tag? What's your expected output? Do you want `class=\"...\"` or just the `\"...\"`?

Comment: @skamazin Yes something like class = "class_name" href =".." etc But these attributes are optional and their sequence are not predefined

Comment: I don't really care about the sequence so long as it's stuff all word characters, my answer below should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @skamazin can we somehow update the below menthod regex to search only anchor tags

Comment: Could you supply a bigger text snippet in your original question? I'll try to make it work, but I don't know the exception to my regex if I don't have the input

Comment: This one doesn't have escaped quotes though. So which is it, [`\"`] or just [`"`].

Comment: @skamazin <p><br></p><h1>A beautiful <a class=\"f-link\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"fake.com/abc.html\">jQuery</a>; WYSIWYG text editor</h1><h3 class=\"text-light\">Froala WYSIWYG Editor is built on the latest technologies and according to the latest industry trends.</h3><p><br></p><p><br></p>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58487/discussion-between-skamazin-and-railsenthusiast).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression to try to parse HTML. HTML can be expressed too many ways and still be valid, yet it will break your pattern and code.

The correct way to get the values for the parameters is to use a parser. [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is the defacto XML/HTML parser for Ruby:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(' <a class=\"direct_link\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://google.com\">link text</a>')
```

That parses the document into a DOM and returns it.

```
link = doc.at('a')
```

`at` finds the *first* instance using the CSS `'a'` selector. (If you want to iterate over them all you can use `search`, which returns a NodeSet, which is akin to an Array.)

At this point `link` is a Node, which we can consider to be like a pointer to the `<a>` tag.

```
link.to_h # => {"class"=>"\\\"direct_link\\\"", "rel"=>"\\\"nofollow\\\"", "target"=>"\\\"_blank\\\"", "href"=>"\\\"http://google.com\\\""}
```

That is the link's parameters and their values turned into a hash. Or, you can directly access the parameters, using `keys`, or their `values`:

```
link.values # => ["\\\"direct_link\\\"", "\\\"nofollow\\\"", "\\\"_blank\\\"", "\\\"http://google.com\\\""]
link.keys # => ["class", "rel", "target", "href"]
```

Or treat it like a hash and iterate over the key/value pairs:

```
link.each do |k, v|
  puts 'parameter: "%s" value: "%s"' % [k, v]
end
# >> parameter: "class" value: "\"direct_link\""
# >> parameter: "rel" value: "\"nofollow\""
# >> parameter: "target" value: "\"_blank\""
# >> parameter: "href" value: "\"http://google.com\""
```

The advantage to using the parser, is that the HTML format can change and the parser is still able to figure it out, and your code won't care. The following format works just as good as the tag used above:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(' <a 
  class=\"direct_link\" 
    rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\"
    href=\"http://google.com\">
    link text
    </a>')
```

Try doing that with a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want does the stuff in the quotes it would be this:

```
"([\w:\/.]+)\\"
```

[Test it here](http://regex101.com/r/tT4oR1/1)

Otherwise if you want the name before the quotes it would be this:

```
(\w+=\\"[\w:\/.]+\\")
```

[Test it here](http://regex101.com/r/tT4oR1/2)

This one matches tags without backslashes:

```
(\w+="[\w:\/.-]+")
```

[Test it here](http://regex101.com/r/tT4oR1/3)